# createBitmap simple crop android

Tags: java, android, cordova, image-processing, createbitmap

Code im using:

```
Bitmap cropImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, cropW, cropH, newWidth, newHeight);
```

Not a java programmer but as i understand it everything is from top left.

my dimensions are

```
cropW: '696',
cropH: '72',
newWidth: '1200',
newHeight:'1800',
```

But i end up with the top left of the image..

What i really would like would be like give it 4 points and it takes out the image in the middle.

Im using this as a plugin with Cordova/Phonegap if it makes a difference.

Any help or explanation would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Below Function

```
public  Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bm) {

    int sice = Math.min((bm.getWidth()), (bm.getHeight()));

    Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bm, sice, sice);

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);


    int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

    canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);
    //canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

 return output;
```

}

Comment: There is a lot of black area around the cropped selection, how do i get rid of that.  Thanks